# How to prevent end users accessing site contents,site setting page through URL

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-settings, site-contents, restricted-access

Is there any way I can prevent end users from accessing the `site setting page`,`site contents` page by directly entering/ typing in the browser. Except a custom `SPGroup`,`site collection admin` nobody should access the `site settings`, `site contents`.

there are chances that, those who are smart end users, they will directly type the `/15/viewlsts.aspx` url or  `/settings.aspx` in he browser to see the contents. I need to avoid this situation, such that when the end user types the url , if he is not site collec.admin or from a particular SPGroup [ in my case , mycustomSPGroup] he should get `access denied` message.

Answer (score 1):

Add a javascript file as a UserCustomAction scriptlink, 
that will execute on every page.. system pages also

You can check `document.location.href` and do whatever you want.

Instead of checking rights you can check for failure with javascript:

```
try {

 //do something only admins can do, like accessing a List only they have access to

} catch(e) {

 //user without those rights will cause a JavaScript error end up here
 document.location="/youhavenorightstothesepages.aspx"
}
```